# Bind on(keyup) to dynamic elements in jQuery (Twitter Bootstrap + typehead)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-events, keyup

I guess some of you must have frowned eyebrows reading this title eh ? I'm sure people asks this every time, yet, I haven't seen my particular question around so, I'm trying ! Binding events to dynamically created elements is my kryptonite, I just can't wrap my head around it ...

So ok, I'm using Twitter Boostrap, with the `typehead()` plugin. I'm using [this trick](https://gist.github.com/1848558) to make it work with remote sources of data. At this point, everything work. I click on a text input in my form, tagged for it, and the scripts go load external sources and the drop down appears. But I have dynamic element creation, and you've figured, it just won't work on them. I was exploring the `live()` method, but looking at "how" the scripts is getting fired, I'm just not sure how I can implement it.

```
$('#anInputField').typeahead().on('keyup', function(ev){
 // stuff happens
});
```

Every time there is a keyup, the script fires a jSON request, checks his things, and gets the result back to `typehead()` who does the autocomplete part of the job. So how can I say to jQuery to look at #aDropdownID created after the initial binding? I went on and checked if I could use `live()`, but since `on()` replaces it... I'm clueless !

Any help appreciated !

Answer (score 46, accepted):

For `on()` to be able to delegate you have to call it on a static element that you know is always going to be there and then you pass the dynamic element like:

```
$('#static-parent').on('keyup', '#aDropdownID', function(ev){
 // stuff happens
});
```

If you don't have a static parent element, then you can always use `body`.

Comment: So <p> or <div> can have "keyup" events?

Comment: The `keyup` event happens on `#aDropdownID`. I can't tell what that is without html..

Comment: Not really clear on my part,true. Just edited the id name so it's more clever. Other then that, on the page itself, it looks like ` <div class="controls" id="idOne"><p><input name="one" type="text" data-provide="typeahead"> <input name="two"> <input name="three" type="text"></p></div>` and it's the <p>[...]</p> that get repeated dynamically on demand.

Comment: (Looking at that soon, will be back with the results!)

Comment: Nope, won't work. Curently, with the non dynamic element, it works like this: `$('input[id^="autocomplete"]').typeahead().on('keyup', function(ev){ //doing things });` ... If I try to replace the selector with #idOne, even the not dymanic one is broken. I guess typehead (or keyup, for that matter) fires only on input elements  ?

Comment: Okay, I searched up a little bit, it seems that the "keyup" event is triggered with only focusable elements (which are mainly input (and other form elements) and A elements ?). Seems that until I can wrap up the things in a A, it's a no go?

Comment: If you don't have a static parent element, then you can always use document.

Comment: Perfect! I used the $('body') as the static element.

Answer (score 15):

This works for me:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#YourInputFieldId', function () {
    //stuff happens
});
```